# How to put implement a session into an echo to echo a variable to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having problems implementing my $myimage into my echos for session.My goal is to put the $myimage into the echo but idk how to do it so i am hoping someone who comes across my post does.I have a gallery of photos and at the moment when i click on something it doesnt send the photo i clicked on rather on the last photo i added.

```
    <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

    $myimage="".$row['image']."";

    $_SESSION['myimage'] = $myimage;

    echo "<div class='img-single'>
    <a href='images/fpage.php'><img class='i' src='images/".$row['image']."'>
    </a><figcaption class='figcaption'>".$row['image_text']."</figcaption> 
    </div>";  
    }
    ?>



    trying to make something look like this

    <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

   //$myimage="".$row['image']."";

    $_SESSION['myimage'] = $myimage;

    echo "<div class='img-single'>
    <a href='images/fpage.php'><img class='i' 
    src='images/$myimage="".$row['image']."";'>
    </a><figcaption class='figcaption'>".$row['image_text']."</figcaption> 
    </div>";  
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a session? If I understand the question correctly, all you have to do in your loop, is add the id of the image to the link to pass it to the next page. Something like `<a href='images/fpage.php?image_id={$row['id']}'>`.

Comment: because if i want to send over a huge amount of text its too big and wont carry over to the 2nd page

Comment: That doesn't make sense; right now you are only setting the name of the image in the session and overwriting it in the loop so that you always have the last one. If it is a lot of information, you have all the more reason to send only the id so that you can get the correct information from the database again in the next page.

Comment: i see im still very new to php.If i use ur method what would i have to put on my 2nd page?